# Cant use std::istream::get

Tags: c++, std

I want use the 6th implementation of std::istream::get(...) method.
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get
It takes basic_streambuf& and char_type. I write:

```
char quote = '\'';
std::stringstream str;
input.get(str, quote); //input is std::istream object
```

But compiler as if it doesn't see this implementation, it try convert stringstream to char*:

error C2664: 'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits> &std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits>::get(_Elem *,std::streamsize)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::stringstream' to '_Elem *'

Couldn't find answer for this. What's wrong? Thanks for help

Comment: `std::stringstream` is not a `streambuf`.

Comment: what is the actual aim? `get` is already rather low level, maybe there is a simpler way

Comment: "The I/O stream objects std::basic_istream and std::basic_ostream, as well as all objects derived from them (std::ofstream, std::stringstream, etc), are implemented entirely in terms of std::basic_streambuf." - cppreference. May be I understood this wrong?

Comment: being implemented in terms of something does not mean that `std::basic_istream` is a `std::streambuf`. Note that the standard library uses inheritance rather sparingly

Comment: inheritance diagram can be found here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream

Answer (score 0):

To get the `streambuf` associated with a `std::stringstream`, you need to call `rdbuf()`.

```
input.get(*str.rdbuf(), quote);
```